# curl for a constant magnitude circular vector field

Tags: vector-analysis

I'm not sure if my understanding about curl is correct but I hope someone can show me the truth. According to the definition, curl of a vector field is:

$(\nabla \times \textbf {F} )(p)\cdot \hat {\textbf {n}} \ {\overset {\underset {\textrm {def} }{}}{=}}\lim _{A\to 0}{\frac {1}{|A|}}\oint _{C}\textbf {F} \cdot \textrm {d} \textbf {r} $

so at a point where field direction is tangent to the radius of the area and magnitude is a constant (i.e., 1), like the following:

[image]

the curl will be:

$(\nabla \times \textbf {F} )(p)\cdot \hat {\textbf {n}} =\lim _{r\to 0}{\frac {1}{\pi r^2}}2 \pi r \hat {\textbf {n}}= \lim _{r\to 0} \frac{2}{r}\hat {\textbf {n}} = \infty$

but my common sense tell me that is not correct. Did I get it wrong?

Comment: Because of a constant vector field is $C^1$ it should be correct. In therms of common sense I consider it as a vortex, and if the field is constant and with positive magnitude it has sense that reducing radius it has to improve infinitely his "rotational speed". As in a vortex of water, indeed.

Comment: not sure. but could you explain how curl can be compared to speed? the definition does not involve time.

Comment: I put "speed" between " " because it's intended as the intuitive idea of how much the direction of the field varies in the space. So the speed is intended here as variation of direction in function of spaces. In poor words how much the field rotates. Also when I wrote that the field is constant I meant that its magnitude is constant.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration.